# Date in UTC zone in Java using Joda-Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, utc

I need to convert [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) date/time to `java.util.Date`. I'm doing as follows.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter=DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime("2-Oct-2013 11:34:26 AM").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This displays date/time represented by UTC zone as expected. In this case, it is `2013-10-02T06:04:26.000Z`

When this `dateTime` is converted to `java.util.Date` as follows,

```
System.out.println(dateTime.toDate());
```

it shows, `Wed Oct 02 11:34:26 IST 2013`. It should be in the `UTC` format.

Is there a way to represent a `Date` in `UTC` after converting it from Joda-Time?

<sub>I want a date to be stored into a database as represented by the `UTC` zone.  `org.joda.time.DateTime` needs to be converted to `java.util.Date` (or `java.sql.Timestamp`) before inserting it to a database. How to overcome this situation?</sub>

Comment: [Fact # 1] The java.util.Date class has no time zone assigned to its date-time value. [Fact # 2] Yet a j.u.Date’s `toString` method confusingly applies the JVM's default time zone. Your JVM has a default time zone of +05:30 (such as "Asia/Kolkata"). That time zone as applied when the `printlin` implicitly called the java.util.Date’s `toString` method. Upshot: **Joda-Time has *nothing* to do with this issue**. The issue/problem lies with the badly designed and implemented java.util.Date class. Avoid j.u.Date whenever possible.

Comment: @BasilBourque : but that works in Hibernate using `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime`, for example.

Comment: Your comment refers to classes *outside* Joda-Time and *outside* your Question. That [class](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/jadira/usertype/dateandtime/joda/PersistentDateTime.html) is a converter, presumably adding behavior. Irrelevant to the two issues in your Q: (a) The "Wed…" string you expected to be in UTC but is instead in your JVM's default time zone (India time) is the correct but confusing behavior of j.u.Date's `toString` method as I said in my comment "Fact # 2". (b) Getting Joda-Time to use UTC. Confusion will ensue until you master the two facts in my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` object per definition is always in UTC!
(timestamp is the number of millis since 1.1.1970 UTC)

But you have to set the timeZone to utc before time formating:

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")

SimpleDateFormatter df = new SimpleDateFormatter (PATTERN);
df.setTimeZone(utc);

System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

In your code you used the `java.util.Date.toString()` method which uses your system default TimeZone.

Comment: yes, I updated the wrong code, and changed to getTimeZone(I) as suggested. (I wrote it down without using developping environment).

Answer (score 2):

## `java.util.Date` String Output is Not UTC

From your Question:

> it shows, Wed Oct 02 11:34:26 IST 2013. It should be in the UTC format.

No it should *not* be in UTC format. That may be what you want, but that is not how the class’ behavior is documented.

Your code:

```
System.out.println(dateTime.toDate());
```

…is first converting a Joda-Time `DateTime` to a `java.util.Date` object, and then implicitly calling the `toString` method on that j.u.Date object. The documented behavior of a j.u.Date for its `toString` method is to apply the JVM's currently default time zone to the generated string. Internally, the j.u.Date is indeed in UTC, but its generated string is not. This behavior of its `toString` was a well-intentioned but ultimately very poor design decision of the Java team that has caused no end of confusion to countless programmers. But it the documented behavior. You should always carefully read a library's documentation rather than assume the library behaves the way you imagine.

## Show Joda-Time `DateTime` In UTC

From your Question:

> Is there a way to represent a Date in UTC after converting it from Joda-Time?

Yes, generating a string representation of a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is easy and clear, unlike dealing with java.util.Date/.Calendar/SimpleDateFormat. Simply call `withZone` to instantiate a new DateTime based on the original but adjusted to another time zone.

A little example source code in Joda-Time 2.5 should make it obvious. Also search StackOverflow for hundreds of more examples using Joda-Time.

```
DateTimeZone zoneMontréal = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime nowInMontréal = DateTime.now( zoneMontréal );

DateTimeZone zoneKolkata = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime nowInKolkata = nowInMontréal.withZone( zoneKolkata ); // Instantiating a new date-time object based on the original but adjusted for another time zone.

DateTime nowInUtc = nowInMontréal.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ); // Ditto, new object, adjusted time zone.
```

When dumped to console by calling `toString` on each DateTime:

```
nowInMontréal: 2014-11-14T02:03:19.932-05:00
nowInKolkata: 2014-11-14T12:33:19.932+05:30
nowInUtc: 2014-11-14T07:03:19.932Z
```

All three of these represent the same simultaneous moment in the timeline of the Universe. Montréal time is five hours behind UTC, India time is five and a half hours ahead of UTC. Same moment, but different wall clock times.

## Put a Joda-Time `DateTime` in Database

From your Question:

> I want a date to be stored into a database as represented by the UTC zone.  org.joda.time.DateTime needs to be converted to java.util.Date (or java.sql.Timestamp) before inserting it to a database. How to overcome this situation?

Easy. Construct a [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object by passing the count of milliseconds since Unix epoch. Note that count must be a `long` not an `int`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp( dateTime.getMillis() );
```

Tip: Be aware of the nature of your database's date-time data types. [Postgres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) for example has excellent support for such types including those defined by the SQL spec. Many database do not, sporting old legacy types or only a few weak types. Read the doc and experiment to make sure you understand the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

public Date toDate(TimeZone timeZone)

> Get the date time as a java.util.Date using the specified time zone.
>
> The Date object created has exactly the same fields as this date-time, except when the time would be invalid due to a daylight savings gap. In that case, the time will be set to the earliest valid time after the gap.
>
> In the case of a daylight savings overlap, the earlier instant is selected.
>
> Converting to a JDK Date is full of complications as the JDK Date constructor doesn't behave as you might expect around DST transitions. This method works by taking a first guess and then adjusting. This also handles the situation where the JDK time zone data differs from the Joda-Time time zone data.
>
> Unlike toDate(), this implementation does not rely on Java's synchronized time zone initialization logic, and should demonstrate better concurrent performance characteristics.

So this would look like:

```
Timezone utc = Timezone.getTimezone("UTC")
System.out.println(dateTime.toDate(utc));
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Have you tried putting it into a simpledateformat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Yes, because you are passing it a date object, i think you need to format it again before you print. Try formatting it one more time the print from that, see what happens. Sorry if this isn't amazingly helpful.

Comment: The method `DateTime#toDate(TimeZone timeZone)` doesn't exist. I can only see `DateTime#toDate()` in the API. Are you sure?

Comment: @Tiny A method `DateTime#toDate(TimeZone timeZone)` makes no sense. A java.util.Date has no time zone (is UTC). The `toDate` method knows this and always adjusts its own date-time value to UTC when creating the j.u.Date. So no need to specify a time zone as an argument. So **this answer’s example code is entirely incorrect**, using  a method that does not exist and conceptually confused as well. Correct and simple code would be: `java.util.Date date = myJodaTimeDateTime.toDate(); // No time zone argument involved.`

Comment: @MuhammadHijazi Please note that your Answer’s code example is incorrect. (a) Non-existing method signature, (b) Conceptually confused, makes no sense to pass a time zone as java.util.Date is always in UTC. See my comment above.